# How to read this function in C?

Tags: c, php-internals

While reading about PHP Zend Engine internals, I came across function
    `zend_parse_parameters()` which is used as the following

`if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "l", &number) != SUCCESS) {
      return;
}`

I am confused about the first parameter as this consists of two separate entities separated by space: `ZEND_NUM_ARGS()` and `TSRMLS_CC`. I have never seen such thing in C like this. Can someone explain how to comprehend this within C syntax rules?
The prototype of `zend_parse_parameters()`is as under:

`int zend_parse_parameters(int num_args TSRMLS_DC, char *type_spec, ...)`

Comment: `TSRMLS_CC` is a macro that either expands into something starting with a comma or nothing at all

Answer (score 0):

From the C point of view `ZEND_NUM_ARGS`, `TSRMLS_CC` and `TSRMLS_DC` are just macros. They are specific to Zend internals. This article explain their usage and to what they would expand:
http://blog.golemon.com/2006/06/what-heck-is-tsrmlscc-anyway.html